# convert time zone sql with string datetime

Tags: sql, date, timezone, date-conversion

I have a time in the format: DD-mon-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM/PM in UTC time. I'd like to convert this to another time zone, but am having some trouble. Below is my code, but Oracle SQL Developer is saying date format not recognized.

```
Select From_Tz(Cast(To_Date('17-FEB-14 04.00.00.000000000 PM',
 'DD-mon-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') As Timestamp), 'UTC')
 AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as "Local Time"
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the format you need is `DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM`.  See [this reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).